# Where do I put viewport meta tag in jsfiddle

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

In jsFiddle I need to put viewport metatag in the `head` element. But since jsFiddle already includes html, head and body tags, it shows a warning: "No need for the HTML tag, it's already in the output."

Is there a way to put viewport metatag in the head?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Comment: **[jsbin](http://jsbin.com)** and **[codepen](http://codepen.io)** both do what jsfiddle does while also allowing access to `<head>` etc

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One way to edit a jsFiddle's `head` tag is to use the [CSS panel `style` hack](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/hacks.html#css-panel-hack).

> If there is a need to edit the header, one can close the `style` element
>   and access the header. After all modifications, please open the `style`
>   tag again.
>
> ```css
> /* your custom CSS */
> </style>
> <!-- access to the HEAD element -->
> <style>
> ```
>
> Inserting the above code into the CSS panel will change the CSS section of the `head` to
>
> ```html
> <style type='text/css'>
> /* your custom CSS */
> </style>
> <!-- access to the HEAD element -->
> <style>
> </style>
> ```

Alternatively, if you're a bit more flexible and are okay with editing the viewport after the page has been loaded, you may use JavaScript or jQuery.

#### JavaScript

```js
var viewport = document.createElement("meta");
viewport.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');
viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(viewport);
```

#### jQuery

```js
$('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />');
```

Comment: When I look at the source code for the embedded page, I don't see my meta tag anywhere  (and indeed, it doesn't seem to be working)

Comment: Im running iOS 9.0.1 on my iphone and it is not working for me, I also tried other examples but actually I cannot find a way to create a JSFiddle mobile friendly page

Comment: The jQuery method does not work, it puts the tags in the html but that is worthless since it happens after the server renders the page and the css method doesnt work because these tags have to be first in the head and that puts them near the bottom

Comment: I don't think any of this can work (anymore?) because jsfiddle forces the 'Result' to be in an iframe and only the window.top.document's viewport meta tag is honored.  These ways only modify the iframe's document.  Attempting to modify window.top.document instead hits a security restriction since the domains are strictly different.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [CSS panel style hack](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/hacks.html#css-panel-hack) mentioned by Saturnix, I created a template on jsFiddle ready for you to fork (already with the viewport meta tag included):

http://jsfiddle.net/andreasbossard/9c3gS/

Here the code of the css for your reference:

```
<style type='text/css'>
/* your custom CSS \*/
</style>
<!-- access to the HEAD element -->
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width' />
<style>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

The methods shown in other answers dont actually work.

1. The jQuery method does not work, it puts the tags in the html but that is worthless since it happens after the server renders the page
2. The CSS method does not work,  because these tags have to be first in the head and that puts them near the bottom

The only way I have found to truly test my jsFiddles on mobile is to use php to get the fiddle content and modify it to insert the tags at the top of the `head`.

#### This is the php script I wrote to do that:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['url'])){

    $url = $_GET['url'].'show/light/';

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $pattern = "/<head>([^;]*); charset=UTF-8\">/";
    $replacement = "<head>\n<meta charset='utf-8'>\n<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>\n<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>";
    echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
    exit;
}
else{
    echo 'You must provide a jsFiddle url via the get parameter "url" like: ?url=http://jsfiddle.net/abcdef';
    exit;
}
```

To use this script, simply host it somewhere online and call it with your jsFiddle's url as the `url` get parameter like:

http://dodsoftware.com/shared-resources/php/jsfiddle-bs-fix.php?url=http://jsfiddle.net/ivangrs/v3ajg1wx/

Comment: [I like](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37732980/creating-first-jquery-slideshow-plugin-converting-from-javascript/37906355#comment63244659_37732980) [your attitude](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37732980/creating-first-jquery-slideshow-plugin-converting-from-javascript/37906355#comment63259624_37838131) ;)

Answer (score 1):

As previously stated by others (but hidden below the fold in the comments) none of the answers will work.

The jsfiddle embed places your code inside of an iframe.  The viewport meta tag is only applied if it's on the outermost page.  See this bug I filed with jsfiddle for examples: https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/1094.

There is really only one solution, to host the files yourself.  And if you have a place to publish an html file, then you don't really need the fiddle anymore.  If you really want to bother, you simply need to add the header to your own page, then add the jsfiddle embed to that.

However, if you just want to see what it will render like on mobile on your own desktop without publishing the file yourself you can do the following:

1. copy the embedded result url into a chrome browser.
2. open the developer tools.
3. in the source tab in the dev tools, edit the  tag "... as HTML...".
4. insert the meta tag:
   `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />`
5. click outside of edit window to apply the change.
6. toggle the device toolbar and select the mobile device of your choice.