# device width on jsfiddle

Tags: mobile, jsfiddle

I want to use a meta tag to set device width on jsfiddle.net

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
```

but meta tags aren't allowed. Is it simply not possible? The mobile sync mode also doesn't auto enable it.

Comment: I think [codepen](http://codepen.io/) allows them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can manipulate the DOM's head using jQuery or Javascript.

**jQuery**

```
$('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />');
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementByTagName('head').innerHTML += '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />';
```

Comment: This does not actually work, it puts the tags in the html but that is worthless since it happens after the server renders the page and after all the frameworks are loaded, try it with a jsfiddle that uses bootstrap and youll see. [Here is a working solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37519562/1376624) for anyone else that runs into this issue

Comment: _I want to use a meta tag to set device width on *jsfiddle.net*_