# How to implement the viewport meta tag to preview responsive websites on jsfiddle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, jsfiddle

I'm trying to preview this JSFiddle ( https://jsfiddle.net/petebere/11pkvt59/show/ ) code on my android mobile phone.

For some reason the viewport meta tag does not work despite implementing the 'CSS panel style hack' solution recommended in this SO question ( [Where do I put viewport meta tag in jsfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16929613/where-do-i-put-viewport-meta-tag-in-jsfiddle) ).

Would you know how to correct this?

JSFiddle HTML code:

```
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p id='para'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cum ea modo dolor disputationi, te eum habeo movet conceptam. Essent moderatius eu has, ex has omnis deleniti. Mei eirmod argumentum et. Iusto labore te eum. Quis animal postulant quo id. Duo euismod dignissim in, nullam liberavisse theophrastus has te.
    </p>
```

JSFiddle CSS code:

```
    p {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        max-width: 350px;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        color: #b1b1b1;
    }

    /* 'CSS panel style hack' to access the head element on JSFiddle */
    </style>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `</style>` tag first and then `<meta>` tag then `<style>` tag ??

Comment: Apparently it's a CSS hack to access the head tag in JSFiddle. It's explained in the SO answer linked in my question and also in the JSFiddle documentation: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/hacks.html#css-panel-hack